# numpy.float32 to float conversion dont work

Tags: python, numpy

I have a number of type numpy.float32 that i want to dump into a json file so i need to convert to float previously but when i execute int(number) the change is not correct.

I have a list with numpy.float32 numbers

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
array.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of "extracting" a `float32`:

```
In [86]: z=np.float32(1.234)
In [87]: z.tolist()             # also used to make a list of Python numbers
Out[87]: 1.2339999675750732
In [88]: type(_)
Out[88]: float
In [89]: z.item()               # also for a single item array
Out[89]: 1.2339999675750732
In [90]: type(_)
Out[90]: float
In [91]: float(z)               # only for single item array
Out[91]: 1.2339999675750732
In [92]: type(_)
Out[92]: float
In [93]: int(z)                 # truncates the float
Out[93]: 1
```